# Unable to instantiate module on production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

I just pushed my program onto heroku and the page I had testing angular loaded with the following error:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module diceAngularApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: t

It was working perfectly fine in development so I'm not sure what the problem could be.  To see the error you can visit the page at www.firexion.com/dice

I'm not sure exactly where the problem could be located so I'm not sure exactly which code to share. Here's the link to the github for it: https://github.com/Firexion/hundred

My guess is it could be in the angular app.js maybe?:

```
'use strict';

angular
.module('diceAngularApp', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngRoute'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/dice', {
    templateUrl: '../../views/dice/main.html',
    controller: 'DiceController'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/dice'
  });
});
```

or maybe I included it wrong in my rails application javascript file, lumen.js:

```
// Lumen
// Bootswatch
//= require jquery-2.1.0
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require lumen/loader
//= require lumen/bootswatch

// angular
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular/angular-cookies
//= require angular/angular-resource
//= require angular/angular-route
//= require angular/angular-sanitize
//= require angular/angular-scenario

// dice
//= require dice/app.js
//= require dice/controllers/main.js
//= require dice/dice.js
```

Thank you for whatever help you can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My strong suspicion, based upon the fact that Angular is looking for a provider for the variable t and I am guessing you would not name a service/controller/etc. t is that you're using minification/compiler somewhere that is clobbering your variables.

To get around this and be safe with a compiler, you need to adjust your syntax. Full details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) but the skinny is below.

```
myapp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('hello/:queryId', {
    templateUrl: 'mypartial.html',
    controller: MyCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
    resolve: {
      'myParam': ['myService', '$route', function(myService, $route) {
        return myService.get($route.current.params.queryId);
      }]
    }
  });
```

Comment: Ok, I've been trying to follow that and I "think" my app.js is already set up properly to prevent this? You're correct that I didn't name anything t. It looks like it's trying to refer to the $routeProvider as t and as far as I can tell, I'm not passing it in incorrectly.  Very confused. I don't think I have anything set up to minify this, maybe it's something heroku does for you?

Comment: Oh, looks like rails had a default setting to use uglifier for compression on production but not dev. Seems that may be the culprit for the minification, but I'm still not sure what's wrong with my app.js and main.js causing the provider to fail to get past the minifier since I don't think it's being referred to by variable anywhere

Comment: Ok, I'm just gonna write this one up to a bad day. I tried turning uglifier off and pushed it to heroku, nothing. Pulled it back down and noticed that I'd forgotten multiplication in one of my controller functions. Figured I may as well push that change to heroku, cause why not, and all of a sudden the page works perfectly??? I don't get it, but it's working and I thank you dearly for your advice with the minification

Comment: I change my controllers and configs to this notation and bug is solved. Thanks !!

Comment: I still don't get it really? What is the problem here exactly then? I am trying to push my application to production but the fact that I use coffescript makes understanding this answer even harder.