# Angular + Rails app is not working on heroku - Failed to instantiate module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, compiler-errors, ngroute

The code is working well in local. But after I deployed to heroku. I get the following error. `[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Angular due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e`

If I remove ngRoute, and move the home template to application/index page, then it'll work fine on herok.

The code is really simple.

app.js

```
angular.module('Angular', [
    'ngRoute',
    'templates'
]).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/assets/ng-app/templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    });
```

});

home.js

```
angular.module('Angular')
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope',  function($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'hi';
}]);
```

application/index.html.erb `<div ng-view class="view-frame animate-view"></div>`

layout/index.html.erb `<div ng-app="Angular"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a full notation for the dependencies in your routeProvider config:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
       ...
    }
]);
```

Here's related topic: [Unable to instantiate module on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851053/unable-to-instantiate-module-on-production). And this solves my problem.